# How can I compare a value in a column to the previous one using R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe in R composed of 4 columns and thousands of lines.
Here are the first lines as an example:

```
     ID     V1      V2     Stimulus
[1,]  001   74.80   803.0   0
[2,]  001   75.98   790.9   0
[3,]  001   75.95   791.1   0
[4,]  001   65.70   918.7   0
[5,]  001   59.63   1005.6  13
[6,]  001   59.44   1012.0  13
[7,]  001   59.62   1010.0  13
[8,]  001   63.85   942.4   13
[9,]  001   60.75   992.9   0
[10,] 001   59.62   1010.0  0
[11,] 001   61.68   974.0   0
[12,] 001   65.21   921.4   15
[13,] 001   59.23   1012.0  15
[14,] 001   61.23   979.5   15
[15,] 001   70.80   849.2   0
```

In this dataframe each row corresponds to 1 second. Column 4 (Stimulus) is either a 0 (i.e. no stimulus) or a positive integer greater than 0 (i.e. stimulus number). Stimulus numbers are always separated by one or more 0 values).

I'd like to learn how to compare each one of the numeric values in column 4 (Stimulus) with the value in the previous row: from this comparison I want to create a 5th column in the dataframe where I write "PRE" if the value is 0, "OK" when the value changes (but just for the first 2 rows/seconds) and "POST" for the remaining numerical rows different than 0 before a new 0 value is presented again.

This is an example of what I'd like to obtain from the previous dataframe

```
         ID     V1      V2     Stimulus    Status
    [1,]  001   74.80   803.0   0           PRE
    [2,]  001   75.98   790.9   0           PRE
    [3,]  001   75.95   791.1   0           PRE
    [4,]  001   65.70   918.7   0           PRE
    [5,]  001   59.63   1005.6  13          OK
    [6,]  001   59.44   1012.0  13          OK
    [7,]  001   59.62   1010.0  13          POST
    [8,]  001   63.85   942.4   13          POST
    [9,]  001   60.75   992.9   0           PRE
    [10,] 001   59.62   1010.0  0           PRE
    [11,] 001   61.68   974.0   0           PRE
    [12,] 001   65.21   921.4   15          OK
    [13,] 001   59.23   1012.0  15          OK
    [14,] 001   61.23   979.5   15          POST
    [15,] 001   70.80   849.2   0           PRE
```

Notice that in rows 7,8 and 14 I have the value "POST" (OK Value is attributed just to the first 2 rows when a change from a value of 0 is detected).

I'm not sure how to solve this. My idea is the following:
I should loop trough each row in column 4 of my dataframe. For each row *i* 
I should check if it is greater than the previous row

```
 mydataframe$Stimulus[i,4] >  mydataframe$Stimulus[i-1,4]
```

If so I add the value "OK" to the new column but just for the first 2 lines, then I would add the value "POST" in column 5 (Status) till the value of the column 4 (Stimulus) becomes zero.

The 5th column I want to create could also be a separate one-column dataframe with the same number of lines as the original dataframe. It doesn't matter, I could *cbind* it at the and to the original dataframe.

Is my (theoretical) approach fine? Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create the new colum (`dat` is the name of your dataset):

```
Status <- ave(dat[ , "Stimulus"], c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(dat[ , "Stimulus"])))),
              FUN = function(x)
                      if(!x[1]) "PRE" else c(rep("OK", min(2, length(x))),
                                             rep("POST", length(x) - 2)))
```

Now, combine both objects:

```
cbind(dat, Status)
```

The result:

```
      ID    V1     V2 Stimulus Status
[1,]   1 74.80  803.0        0    PRE
[2,]   1 75.98  790.9        0    PRE
[3,]   1 75.95  791.1        0    PRE
[4,]   1 65.70  918.7        0    PRE
[5,]   1 59.63 1005.6       13     OK
[6,]   1 59.44 1012.0       13     OK
[7,]   1 59.62 1010.0       13   POST
[8,]   1 63.85  942.4       13   POST
[9,]   1 60.75  992.9        0    PRE
[10,]  1 59.62 1010.0        0    PRE
[11,]  1 61.68  974.0        0    PRE
[12,]  1 65.21  921.4       15     OK
[13,]  1 59.23 1012.0       15     OK
[14,]  1 61.23  979.5       15   POST
[15,]  1 70.80  849.2        0    PRE
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works great! What would I put in the else statement if, instead of OK and POST I wanted to show a progressive number starting from 1 (e.g. 1,2,3 ...) until I meet another 0? I tried with [code]else rep(rownames(dat), length(x)))[/code] it works but it gives me many warnings (In `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x,  ... : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length )

Comment: @Albz You can replace the `else` statement with `seq(x)`. This will generate a sequence from 1 to the length of `x`.