# R - Comparing values in a column and creating a new column with the results of this comparison. Is there a better way than looping?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner of R. Although I have read a lot in manuals and here at this board, I have to ask my first question. It's a little bit the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225038/how-can-i-compare-a-value-in-a-column-to-the-previous-one-using-r) but not really the same and i don't understand the explanation there.
I have a dataframe with hundreds of thousands of rows and 30 columns. But for my question I created a simplier dataframe that you can use:

```
a <- sample(c(1,3,5,9), 20, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(c(1,NA), 20, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Now I want to compare the values of the last column (here column `b`), so that I'm looking iteratively at the value of each row if it is the same as the in the next row. If it is the same I want to write a `0` as the value in a new column in the same row, otherwise it should be a `1` as the value of the new column.

Here you can see my code, that's not working, because the rows of the new column only contain `0`:

```
m<-c()

for (i in seq(along=df[,1])){
    ifelse(df$b[i] == df$b[i+1],m <- 0, m <- 1)          
    df$mov <- m
}
```

The result, what I want to get, looks like the example below. What's the mistake? And is there a better way than creating loops? Maybe looping could be very slow for my big dataset.

```
   a  b mov
1  9 NA   0
2  1 NA   1
3  1  1   1
4  5 NA   0
5  1 NA   0
6  3 NA   0
7  3 NA   1
8  5  1   0
9  1  1   0
10 3  1   0
11 1  1   0
12 9  1   0
13 1  1   1
14 5 NA   0
15 9 NA   0
16 9 NA   0
17 9 NA   0
18 5 NA   0
19 3 NA   0
20 1 NA   0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `set.seed` when using `sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to consider in your example.

First, to avoid a loop, you can create a copy of the vector that is shifted by one position. (There are about 20 ways to do this.) Then when you test vector `B` vs `C` it will do element-by-element comparison of each position vs its neighbor.

Second, equality comparisons don't work with NA -- they always return NA. So `NA == NA` is not `TRUE` it is `NA`! Again, there are about 20 ways to get around this, but here I have just replaced all the `NA`s in the temporary vector with a placeholder that will work for the tests of equality.

Finally, you have to decide what you want to do with the last value (which doesn't have a neighbor). Here I have put `1`, which is your assignment for "doesn't match its neighbor".

So, depending on the range of values possible in `b`, you could do

```
c = df$b 
z = length(c)
c[is.na(c)] = 'x'   # replace NA with value that will allow equality test
df$mov = c(1 * !(c[1:z-1] == c[2:z]),1)     # add 1 to the end for the last value
```

Comment: hi, thank you too, this also works. that's a pitty, that i can only "accept" one answer. but you are closer to my question, so you get the acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to mark the ones which match

```
df$bnext <- c(tail(df$b,-1),NA)
df$bnextsame <- ifelse(df$bnext == df$b | (is.na(df$b) & is.na(df$bnext)),0,1)
```

There are plenty of `NA`s here because there are plenty of `NA`s in your column `b` as well and any comparison with `NA` returns an `NA` and not a `TRUE/FALSE`. You could add a `df[is.na(df$bnextsame),"bnextsame"] <- 0` to fix that.

Comment: The use of if-else is good, but this doesn't work for two consecutive NAs because that comparison always returns `NA`. Also, OP wants zero as the code for the same value, not 1.

Comment: thank you! I got it! the results of zero and 1 are changed, but it doesn't matter for my analysis.

Comment: You're right, @beroe. I would add another condition in the `ifelse` to check if both columns are `NA`.

Comment: @Simon1723, great. I made that edit to match your question anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "rolling equality test" with `zoo` 's `rollapply`. Also, `identical` is preferred to `==`.

```
#identical(NA, NA)
#[1] TRUE
#NA == NA
#[1] NA

library(zoo)

df$mov <- c(rollapply(df$b, width = 2, 
        FUN = function(x) as.numeric(!identical(x[1], x[2]))), "no_comparison")
      #`!` because you want `0` as `TRUE` ;
      #I added a "no_comparison" to last value as it is not compared with any one
df
#   a  b           mov
#1  5  1             0
#2  1  1             0
#3  9  1             1
#4  5 NA             1
#5  9  1             1
#.....
#19 1 NA             0
#20 1 NA no_comparison
```