# Comparing consecutive values in column 1 (col 1) & creating new column (col 2) with col1 post comparison results

Tags: r

i am new to R and am asking a very fundamental question. Definitely, i did my homework while trying to take guidance from examples presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794006/r-comparing-values-in-a-column-and-creating-a-new-column-with-the-results-of-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225038/how-can-i-compare-a-value-in-a-column-to-the-previous-one-using-r), but was unable to implement the idea in my case i.e. perhaps due to greater dimensions of comparisons in my problem.

My actual data has hundred of columns and million of rows but for simplicity, i am pasting only one column of interest. The "Potential" column can have either 1, 2 or 3 as:

```
S.No     Potential
 1           -
 2           1
 3           2
 4           3
 5           1
 6           2
 7           3
 8           1
 9           2
10           3
11           3
12           1
13           1
14           2
15           1
16           3
17           2
18           1
19           2
20           2
21           2
22           3
23           1
24           3
25           2
26           3
27           3
```

I would like to compare the values of the last column (here column Potential) so that i am comparing each [i] row with its immediate predecessor [i-1] and based on this comparison, i would like to have a new column (say column Challenge) with some pre-defined values. Here is pseudo-code of what i want to achieve:

```
if(Potential[i-1] == 1 && Potential[i] == 1 then Challenge[i] <- 1
if(Potential[i-1] == 1 && Potential[i] == 2 then Challenge[i] <- 2
if(Potential[i-1] == 1 && Potential[i] == 3 then Challenge[i] <- 3

if(Potential[i-1] == 2 && Potential[i] == 1 then Challenge[i] <- 4
if(Potential[i-1] == 2 && Potential[i] == 2 then Challenge[i] <- 5
if(Potential[i-1] == 2 && Potential[i] == 3 then Challenge[i] <- 6

if(Potential[i-1] == 3 && Potential[i] == 1 then Challenge[i] <- 7
if(Potential[i-1] == 3 && Potential[i] == 2 then Challenge[i] <- 8
if(Potential[i-1] == 3 && Potential[i] == 3 then Challenge[i] <- 9
```

The correct final output would be something like this:

```
 S.No     Potential       Challenge
 1           2                -
 2           1                4
 3           2                2
 4           3                6  
 5           1                7
 6           2                2
 7           3                6
 8           1                so on
 9           2                
10           3                
11           3
12           1
13           1
14           2
15           1
16           3
17           2
18           1
19           2
20           2
21           2
22           3
23           1
24           3
25           2
26           3
27           3
```

Also, as my data are large, can i avoid loop? I appreciate your guidance on this in anticipation. Thanks much!

P.S: I definitely tried many syntax of my own but i did not paste it here because it was likely to create unnecessary distraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `data.table` package combined with `shift` and `Reduce` function. Since your logic is somewhat close to a *ternary numeral system*, the new column can be calculated as `Potential[i] + 3 * (Potential[i-1] - 1)`, here the `y` correspond to the lagged value of `Potential` column which actually is the `Potential[i-1]`.

```
library(data.table)

DASlaneoverall$Potential <- as.numeric(DASlaneoverall$Potential)
setDT(DASlaneoverall)[, Challenge := Reduce(function(x, y) x + 3 * (y - 1), 
                                shift(Potential, n = 0:1, type = "lag"))]

DASlaneoverall
    S.No Potential Challenge
 1:    1         2        NA
 2:    2         1         4
 3:    3         2         2
 4:    4         3         6
 5:    5         1         7
 6:    6         2         2
 7:    7         3         6
 8:    8         1         7
 9:    9         2         2
10:   10         3         6
11:   11         3         9
12:   12         1         7
13:   13         1         1
14:   14         2         2
15:   15         1         4
16:   16         3         3
17:   17         2         8
18:   18         1         4
19:   19         2         2
20:   20         2         5
21:   21         2         5
22:   22         3         6
23:   23         1         7
24:   24         3         3
25:   25         2         8
26:   26         3         6
27:   27         3         9
    S.No Potential Challenge
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. In above code, x and y are some generic terms? or do they refer to some of my data frame. I tried your script, but got an error:

Error in y - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: `x` and `y` are parameters of the function passed to the `Reduce` function, they correspond to the original and lagged value of the `Potential` column. The error message is possibly due to your `Potential` column is not a `numeric` class. Try to convert it by `df$Potential <- as.numeric(df$Potential)`, and then try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying this thing.. but do not know why it is giving me error: 

`DASlaneoverall$Challenge <- 25
library(data.table)
DASlaneoverall$Potential <- as.numeric(DASlaneoverall$Potential)
setDT(DASlaneoverall)[, DASlaneoverall$Challenge := Reduce(function(DASlaneoverall$Potential[i], DASlaneoverall$Potential[i-1]) DASlaneoverall$Potential[i] + 3 * (DASlaneoverall$Potential[i-1] - 1),
                                                       shift(DASlaneoverall$Potential, n = 0:1, type = "lag"))]`

Comment: Copy and paste the code above and try again. You don't need to replace `x` and `y`, they are just parameters of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how strict is your logic in terms of numbering of combinations this might work:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, previous := shift(Potential)]
dt[order(previous, Potential), group :=  .GRP , by = .(previous, Potential)]
```

Group number will be assigned to each combination of `Potential[i-1]` and `Potential[i]` in corresponding order:

```
 dt[order(previous, Potential)]
 #     S.No Potential previous group
 # 1:    2         1        -     1
 # 2:   13         1        1     2
 # 3:    3         2        1     3
 # 4:    6         2        1     3
 # 5:    9         2        1     3
 # 6:   14         2        1     3
 # 7:   19         2        1     3
 # 8:   16         3        1     4
```